# Highcharts e C# - JavaScriptSerializer perde o valor após postback (com updatepanel)

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

Estou construindo a categoria (xAxis) e as séries de dados no Highcharts através do JavaScriptSerializer. A estrutura funciona perfeitamente quando utilizo no Page_Load, mas ao realizar postback (click em botão asp dentro de updatepanel), ele perde o valor (testei através de um alert('testeValorQueFicouZerado')).

Como faço para que o valor persista/seja carregado para o gráfico? Abaixo codebehind

```
public string xAxis { get; set; }
public string series1 { get; set; }
public string series2 { get; set; }


(DataTable tabela criada com campo Credenciado, VRE e Valor)

List<string> credL = new List<string>();
List<double> vreL = new List<double>();
string vreTemp = string.Empty;
List<double> valorL = new List<double>();
string valorTemp = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow dr in tabela.Rows)
{
    credL.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["Credenciado"]));
    vreTemp = Convert.ToString(dr["VRE"]).Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("R$ ", string.Empty);
    if (vreTemp == string.Empty)
    {
        vreL.Add(0);
    }
    else
    {
    vreL.Add(Convert.ToDouble(vreTemp));
    }
    valorTemp = Convert.ToString(dr["Recuperado"]).Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("R$ ", string.Empty);
    if(valorTemp == string.Empty)
    {
    valorL.Add(0);
    }
    else
    {
    valorL.Add(Convert.ToDouble(valorTemp));
    }

}

JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializexAxis = new JavaScriptSerializer();
xAxis = jsSerializexAxis.Serialize(credL);

JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializeseries1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
series1 = jsSerializeseries1.Serialize(vreL);

JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializeseries2 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
series2 = jsSerializeseries2.Serialize(valorL);
```

E no html/js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            if (prm != null) {
                prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
                    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                            chart: {
                                renderTo: 'graficoRecuperado',
                                type: 'column'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Valor Recuperado'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: eval('<%=xAxis%>')
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'em reais (R$)'
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'VRE',
                                data: eval('<%=series1%>')
                            }, {
                                name: 'Recuperado',
                                data: eval('<%=series2%>')
                            }]
                        });
                    }
                });
            }; 

</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
            <div id="graficoRecuperado" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
(gridview e outros controles...)
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muitos testes, finalmente encontrei uma solução satisfatória que driblou updatepanel e funcionou embaixo do add_endRequest: criei o gráfico pelo codebehind utilizando o string builder.

trecho:

```
.
.
.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("var div = document.getElementById('graficoRecuperado');");
sb.Append("div.style.display = 'block';");
sb.Append("var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();");
sb.Append("if (prm != null)");
sb.Append("{");
sb.Append("prm.add_endRequest(function(sender, e) {");
sb.Append("chart = new Highcharts.Chart({");
.
.
.
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ChamarFuncaoCriarGrafico", sb.ToString(),true);
```

Ao usuário que negativou a dúvida, seria muito importante que você deixasse um comentário sobre o motivo dessa atitude. Caso seja algo simples para você resolver, que tal ajudar o próximo apresentando um pouco da sua sabedoria? Caso algo esteja errado na abordagem, informe onde está o erro para que seja possível corrigir e manter um questionamento interessante. Negativar simplesmente só recai a dúvida sobre você: não tem conhecimento, tem dificuldade em ler e compreender textos ou falta competência mesmo?